# Angular 8: How to MOCK a Configuration Class (constants & static properties only in the class)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I have an angular app that has the following TypeScript files:

1. AppConstants.ts
2. api.service.ts
3. api.service.spec.ts

Following is the code of the files:

**AppConstants.ts**

```
export class AppConstants {
    public static apiBaseUrl: string; // = 'https://test-stage.unittest.com/#';
    public static taxRate: number = 30.25;
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppConstants } from 'src/Constants';

import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    get(url: string, options?: any): Observable<any> {
        const requestURL = `${AppConstants.apiBaseUrl}${url}`;
        console.log('url---', AppConstants.apiBaseUrl);
        return this.httpClient.get(requestURL, options).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
}
```

**api.service.spec.ts**

```
import { AppConstants } from 'src/Constants';
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'; //
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';

export class MockAppConstants extends AppConstants {
    public static apiBaseUrl = 'test-base-api-url';
}

describe('ApiService', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                ApiService
                // , AppConstants
                ,
                {
                    provide: AppConstants,
                    useClass: MockAppConstants
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    );

    it('should get profile data of user', async(inject([HttpTestingController, ApiService, AppConstants],
        (httpClient: HttpTestingController) => {
            const profileInfo: any = { login: 'blacksonic', id: 602571, name: 'Gábor Soós' };
            const githubService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
            let profileResponse;

            // spyOnProperty(AppConstants, 'apiBaseUrl').and.returnValue('test');

            githubService.get('blacksonic').subscribe((response: any) => {
                profileResponse = response;
                console.log('profile Response after API call', profileResponse);
            });

            httpClient.expectOne('undefinedblacksonic').flush(profileInfo);
            expect(profileResponse).toEqual(profileInfo);
        }))
    );

    it('should be created', () => {
        const service: ApiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I am trying to mock the *AppConstants* with *MockAppConstants* class but the code keep picking the constant values from the original file.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my approach to data mocking?

Answer (score 0):

I believe its due to the static class members, TS will copy the static members to the child class.

Alternative approach without changing your AppConstants.

```
const MockAppConstants = AppConstants(); 
 MockAppConstants.apiBaseUrl = 'test-base-api-url'

{
  provide: AppConstants,
  useValue: MockAppConstants
}
```

Note: 
Using a public static member for your **apiBaseUrl**, could be risky and any instance of the class could potentially change the value which is shared for all objects of that class.

```
export class AppConstants {
    public static apiBaseUrl: string; // = 'https://test-stage.unittest.com/#';
    public static taxRate: number = 30.25;
}
```